# Android in app billing (IAB) onIabSetupFinished not being called

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Working [from this](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html) I have implemented IAB and it appears to be set up correctly as I when i execute

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, "android.test.purchased", 10001,   
           mPurchaseFinishedListener, "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
```

I get sent to the correct IAB to purchase the test.

However the code below never seems to output any logging

```
        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, KEY);

    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
       public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
          if (!result.isSuccess()) {
             // Oh noes, there was a problem.
             Log("Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
          } else {
             Log("onIabSetupFinished " + result.getResponse());
             mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
          }
       }
    });
```

*Note: my own static Log method is being called and there is no problem with it.*

Once set up i want to check for purchases but it doesn't appear to get called, neither does `mPurchaseFinishedListener`.

Anyone know what i may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lunch I switched on debug in IanHelper.java and this code appears to be working now.

```
boolean mDebugLog = true; // Line 75
```

I cannot see any reason why this wasn't working before. Must be user Error, wrong apk installed or something like that! Now we will never know!